# Ubuntu Software Center does not allow changes to software sources

Tags: software-center

The checkboxes that appear to be changeable under the **Edit / Software Sources** dialog box cannot be changed. I click on them and they just turn gray and stay at their current setting.

**Update:**

When I run software-center from a terminal window and try to change one of the checkbox settings, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py",
        line 649, in on_isv_source_toggled
    self.backend.ToggleSourceUse(str(source_entry))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 143, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 630, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException:
  com.ubuntu.SoftwareProperties.PermissionDeniedByPolicy:
  com.ubuntu.softwareproperties.applychanges
```

These things happen instead of it properly prompting me for a password (for root privs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to install: `polkit-kde-1`

After this and a reboot, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this if my /etc/apt/sources.list has bad permissions, ie read-only.

what does

```
ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list
```

show?

It should look like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3881 2011-11-18 16:30 /etc/apt/sources.list
```

You can fix it with

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: That was a good tip. I think that the Software Center is not executing as root and cannot modify this file. It also does not ask me to validate.

Comment: It shouldn't run as root, that's right. But it should ask for your password to elevate it's privileges when it needs to. Not sure why that might not be happening, the only thing I can think to suggest is run "software-center" in a Terminal rather than from the menu and see if there's any revealing errors printed.

Comment: When I run it in a terminal, I get:

Comment: Ok, that looks a bit more involved than a file permissions issue, I'll have to bow out to someone who knows more about DBus